# Compare directories, delete leftover files, copy new ones

Tags: python, python-3.x, filesystems

My hard drive tends to get clogged with old files, and I'd like to use Python to clean them up. I'm trying to create a script that looks at two directories, deletes any files that are not found in the source directory, then copy any new files from said source to the destination.

So far I've only been able to get it to work on the first level of any directory. In other words, it doesn't seem to scan any sub-directories for old files. I've been trying to find a way to recursively look through subs with os.walk and the filecmp module, but have yet to resolve the issue.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import os
import filecmp

def delete_diffs(src, dst):
    dirs = filecmp.dircmp(src, dst)
    for items in dirs.right_only:
        if os.path.isdir(dst + '\\' + items) == True:
           print('Removing ' + items)
           os.system("""rmdir "{0}" /S /Q """.format(os.path.join(dst, items)))
        if os.path.isdir(dst + '\\' + items) == False:
           print('Removing ' + items)
           os.remove(dst + '\\' + items)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `shutil` for copying or deleting whole directories or copying files with (most) properties. `os.path.relpath` can be used in concert with `os.walk` as shown below to walk through one directory and compare with another using the same relative path. The following works for me:

```
import os, filecmp, shutil

def resolve_diffs(src, dst):
    for src_root, src_dirs, src_files in os.walk(src, topdown=True):
        dst_root = os.path.join(dst, os.path.relpath(src_root, src))
        dirs = filecmp.dircmp(src_root, dst_root)
        for item in dirs.right_only:
            print('Removing ' + item)
            dst_path = os.path.join(dst_root, item)
            if os.path.isdir(dst_path):
                shutil.rmtree(dst_path)
            else:
                os.remove(dst_path)
        for item in dirs.left_only:
            print('Adding ' + item)
            src_path = os.path.join(src_root, item)
            if os.path.isdir(src_path):
                shutil.copytree(src_path, os.path.join(dst_root, item))
            else:
                shutil.copy2(src_path, os.path.join(dst_root, item))
```